# Issue in cached bitmap for Direct 2d

Tags: c++, gdi+, direct2d

I am importing my code from GDI+ to Direct2D. The Issue is I am not able to convert the bitmap into cached Bitmap. For GDI there is API like GdipCreateCachedBitmap. Is there any API or way to create cached bitmap in Direct2d.

Comment: Isn't any bitmap in Direct2D "cached" by default, since it's bound to a render target? Do you mean convert it from one pixel format to the pixel format of the render target?

Comment: Cached bitmap in GDI+ is device-specific bitmap, likely some sort of optimization. I don't think you need to look for direct equivalent in Direct2D, just use bitmaps.